# How to use createTempFile in groovy/Jenkins to create a file in non-default directory?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, temporary-files

What I am trying to achieve is to create a temporary file in groovy in workspace directory, but as an example `/tmp/foo` will be good enough.

So, here is perfectly working java code:

```
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Files;

class foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String s="/tmp/foo";
            Path p=Paths.get(s);
            Path tmp=Files.createTempFile(p,"pref",".suf");
            System.out.println(tmp.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

however, when used in context of Jenkins pipeline it simply does not work:

```
def mktemp() {
    //String s=pwd(tmp:true)
    String s="/tmp/foo"
    Path p=Paths.get(s)
    Path tmp=Files.createTempFile(p,"pref",".suf")
    return tmp;
}
```

The result is *array element type mismatch* message with nothing helpful in pipeline log:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: array element type mismatch
        at java.lang.reflect.Array.set(Native Method)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovyCallSiteSelector.parametersForVarargs(GroovyCallSiteSelector.java:104)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovyCallSiteSelector.matches(GroovyCallSiteSelector.java:51)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovyCallSiteSelector.findMatchingMethod(GroovyCallSiteSelector.java:197)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovyCallSiteSelector.staticMethod(GroovyCallSiteSelector.java:191)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onStaticCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:153)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$2.call(Checker.java:184)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedStaticCall(Checker.java:188)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:95)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
        at WorkflowScript.mktemp(WorkflowScript:16)
```

The java.io.File.createTempFile() is not any better. In plain java code it works perfectly. In groovy it throws `java.io.IOException: No such file or directory`.

BTW, `/tmp/foo` directory exists, methods are added on script approval screen.

Comment: problem not in groovy, but in jenkins sandbox. can you run it not in sandbox?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the `IOException` I suspect you're calling `mktemp` from within a `node {}` block and expecting to create the temporary file on that node. Pipeline scripts are run entirely on the Jenkins master. Pipeline steps that interact with the filesystem (e.g. `writeFile`) are aware of `node {}` blocks and will be sent over to the node to be executed there, but any pure-Java methods know nothing about remote nodes and are going to interact with the master's filesystem.